# How to extract numbers after string pattern in pandas DataFrame & create to new feature in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, python-re

Create a new feature Based on column values

example

```
Column 


CHPS CHTN 28 GR 1 ITEM

CHPS CHTN 28 GR 1 ITEM
```

Sample output

```
Column                         A      B


CHPS CHTN 28 GR 1 ITEM        28          1

CHPS CHTN 28 GR 4 ITEM        28          4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have at most 2 numbers to extract, you can use a simple one-liner code, as follows:

```
df.join(df['Column'].str.extract(r'\D*(?P<A>\d+)\D+(?P<B>\d+)'))
```

Here, the column labels are automatically propagated from the names of the *named capturing groups* of the regex used in the [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) call.

Result:

```
                   Column   A  B
0  CHPS CHTN 28 GR 1 ITEM  28  1
1  CHPS CHTN 28 GR 1 ITEM  28  1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str.extractall` and `rename` to change your column names.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import pandas as pd




alpha_cols = dict(
                 enumerate(ascii_uppercase)
                 )


df1  = df.join(df['Column'].str.extractall('(\d+)')\
                    .unstack(1).droplevel(0,1))\
                    .rename(columns=alpha_cols)
```

---

```
print(df1)

                   Column   A  B
0  CHPS CHTN 28 GR 1 ITEM  28  1
1  CHPS CHTN 28 GR 1 ITEM  28  1
```